# What is the 'arm' at the rear of the X-29?

Tags: aircraft-design, experimental-aircraft, x-29

In this image of the [Grumman X-29](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grumman_X-29), there is an 'arm' just above the exhaust nozzle leading forward and, apparently, attached to the right side of the fuselage. What is this and what is it for?

[image]
<sup>Source: Wikipedia [X-29 Article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grumman_X-29)</sup>

I realize this is an experimental aircraft, but it doesn't look like sensors (like the probe off the nose), it looks more like a structure for lifting the plane.

Comment: Similar system on a YF-22: [What is this red canister on the tail of the YF-22?](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/26648/what-is-this-red-canister-on-the-tail-of-the-yf-22)

Comment: Nice virtual single high lift positive cambered airfoil in action.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Two X-29's were built, and the only difference between the two is that #2 has an externally mounted spin recovery chute attached to the tail. That is what you are seeing in this picture. The chute is packed in the tube structure and the "arms" are structural to distribute load.

[Source](http://fas.org/man/dod-101/sys/ac/x-29.htm)

> The only significant difference between the two aircraft was an emergency spin chute deployment system mounted at the base of the rudder on aircraft No. 2.

[Here is a video of the chute deployed](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0PrtM1weNOE)

[And here are more details from NASA on the chute system](http://www.nasa.gov/centers/dryden/multimedia/imagegallery/X-29/EC89-216-5.html)

The reason that #2 needed this and #1 did not is that #2 was going to be conducting experiments at up to 67° angle of attack, where entering a spin was much more likely. #1's AOA was limited to about 21° and was considered the "phase-1" flight dynamics platform, while #2 was the "phase-2" platform.

Comment: To some extent, I was right, it is an arm for lifting the plane. by its chute, right out of a spin... :)